# jenkins - mixed build history after restart

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, hudson

We have different Jenkins-Jobs on the same git repository with different artifacts. And everything works nearly okay for a few weeks.

But since we restarted our server for updates every build history shows us the same ... Also our dashboard shows the wrong build number for the jobs.

http://www.picfront.org/d/8OC6 (cant post images cause of reputation limit)

Like you can see every jobs still has the build number 107 but only the main job is at this number the others are around 30 to 50 ... And as a result every information about builds is a bit incorrect.

Information:

- Buildsystem: Jenkins 1.477 Win XP 32 bit Java 7
- 5 Jobs on the same git-repsoitory
- Building of an Eclipse application and an Andorid applocation

[EDIT]

I also get some Errors in the Jenkins-Log -

```
24.09.2012 13:29:03 hudson.model.RunMap load
WARNUNG: multiple runs claiming to be #41; using run from C:\Jenkins...
```

[EDIT2]

I found out when i add a new FreeStyle Job it will show also the full history of the other jobs after a restart.

Comment: [Solved] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jenkinsci-users/SgSJKBJIClg

Comment: Could you summarize the solution you have found in an answer below?

Comment: done! I didn't know that i can answer myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to set in the global configuration of jenkins a parameterized path where the builds should be saved.
You can find this value under

**Manage Jenkins --> Configure Page --> Advanced Conifguration --> Build Path**

In my case i configured an absolute path and so every build was saved in one directory.And after a restart every job checked this folder an claimed the builds.

Now i have : **${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds**

So every job has it own build directory and the problem is gone.

*Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jenkinsci-users/SgSJKBJIClg*

Comment: I saw this warning message today and came across this thread. Despite having ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds already set for the property 'Build Record Root Directory', i still see warning messages stating 'WARNING: multiple runs claiming to be...'